# Aloglia records are updating with wrong datatypes

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.5, algolia

I am facing some issues in algolia records. There are some attributes in me People table (e.g. id(int), user_id(int), name(varchar) ... etc).

When I add new records through Laravel 5.5 to database then everything works fine at algolia but I try to update record then although records are updating perfectly but the datatypes are changing. Like before Updating record user_id is int = 6 after updating the name or something else the user_id is converting to varchar implicitly.

I dont know whats happening.

before updating this record:

[image]

After updating the same record:

[image]

The insertion code is:

```
 $new_person = People::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'stage_id' => 0,
            'source_id' => 0,
            'agent_id' => 0,
            'custom_field_id' => 0,
            'fname' => $request->first_name,
            'lname' => $request->last_name,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'avatar' => "/images/user.png",
            'name_slug' => createPeopleSlug($request->first_name , $request->last_name)
        ]);
```

The code for update is:

```
$person = People::find($request->personID);
            $person->tags = $tagsString;
            $person->save();
```

I am not expert of Aloglia

Comment: Can you post a screeshot of the model dumped (to see the attributes) and the `->toArray()` version?

Comment: This is my modal code : 

<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class People extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'people';
    }

}

Comment: The issue is resolved by laravel casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will be resolved by adding Laravel casts variable to your Model, simple.

```
protected $casts = [
    'user_id' => 'integer',
    'agent_id' => 'integer',
    'company_person_id' => 'integer',
];
```

Cheers!